# C programming in Windows 7

Tags: c, gui, networking, cryptography, windows-7

Which is the best book and what are the best tools for C programming in Windows 7?

Would using C in any way hinder me when it comes to using the Windows API as opposed to using C++ or C#? I would like to use C, because it seems to me that object-oriented programming is bad for performance and the abstraction seems only counter-productive if the right people are doing the programming. I will mostly do GUIs and background services that do a lot of networking, possibly at OSI Layer 2, and public key + cascaded symmetric key cryptograpy.

Also, the core of the programs (excluding any that deal directly with OSI Layer 2) should be portable to Android.

Comment: Best tool for C programming on Windows without a doubt: [Microsoft Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio). As for the rest of your question: good luck with that.

Comment: You're restricting yourself from using any language remotely supporting a paradigm (C++ for example is quite multi-paradigm: a lot of C++ code, including significant parts of the highly acclaimed Boost library, is "object-oriented" only in that is puts some functions into `struct`s), on the grounds of *performance* and some people not getting their heads around OOP?

Comment: If the question wasn't about Windows programming, I'd suspect you were [Linus Torvalds trolling us](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/57643/focus=57918)...

Comment: Ummm... I have a C program included into Debian and Ubuntu, and another into Sunfreeware. LOL

Comment: @PersonalNexus - You know that Visual Studio 2010 still doesn't have a lot of the features of C99 right? [See here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/526116/c99-support). VS is much more suited to C++ development than C.

Comment: Hi nlovric, you're asking a number of different things at the same time: can you focus one problem at a time and ask about them separately?

Answer (score 3):

Given that the entire Win 32 API is exposed primarily as C functions, there' no hinderance to using C, other than maybe the lack of libraries.

The best book to start with is probably still [Programming Windows](http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/) by Charles Petzold.  It's showing its age, but the basics haven't changed, and all the new stuff can be learned best through MSDN's online reference - which is where you should go once you've gotten started anyway.

The best environment for C under windows is usually Visual Studio.  You can use the express c++ version if you don't want to pay for the bigger versions.  Just use the /TC switch to compile as C code rather than C++.  It does lack some of the newer C features, but it's a solid compiler that works well with Windows.

As to your editorial on C vs C++ programming, it "seems to me" like you're jumping the gun in assuming any performance gains / losses between object-oriented and procedural programming.

Comment: What about the Portland Group PGI C / C++ ([PGI Workstation](http://www.pgroup.com/products/pgiworkstation.htm), [PGI Accelerator Compilers](http://www.pgroup.com/resources/accel.htm)); would that be better? It supports C-99.

Comment: PellesC is another choice.